# Where can I find the rpc api endpoints for electrum?

Tags: electrum, electrum-console

Somehow I cannot find a list of the possible rpc commands. Basically they are just the bitcoin rpc commands I guess but I cannot find a list for that either...

There are some examples here:
http://docs.electrum.org/en/latest/merchant.html#jsonrpc-interface

Also there is a list here but e.g. addrequest from the link above is not in there:
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electrum RPC methods a little different from full bitcoin node RPC. You can run `help` command in order to get all methods. Here is an example:

```
"addrequest",
"addtransaction",
"broadcast",
"clearrequests",
"commands",
"create",
"createmultisig",
"createnewaddress",
"decrypt",
"deserialize",
"dumpprivkeys",
"encrypt",
"freeze",
"getaddressbalance",
"getaddresshistory",
"getaddressunspent",
"getalias",
"getbalance",
"getconfig",
"getfeerate",
"getmasterprivate",
"getmerkle",
"getmpk",
"getprivatekeys",
"getpubkeys",
"getrequest",
"getseed",
"getservers",
"gettransaction",
"getunusedaddress",
"help",
"history",
"importprivkey",
"is_synchronized",
"ismine",
"listaddresses",
"listcontacts",
"listrequests",
"listunspent",
"make_seed",
"notify",
"password",
"payto",
"paytomany",
"restore",
"rmrequest",
"searchcontacts",
"serialize",
"setconfig",
"setlabel",
"signmessage",
"signrequest",
"signtransaction",
"sweep",
"unfreeze",
"validateaddress",
"verifymessage",
"version"
```

Answer (score 0):

Electrum RPC methods list are give below

Methods

```
blockchain.block.subscribe
blockchain.block.unsubscribe
blockchain.block.broadcast

blockchain.address.subscribe
blockchain.address.unsubscribe
blockchain.address.get_history
blockchain.address.get_balance

blockchain.transaction.broadcast
blockchain.transaction.get

blockchain.transactions.guess_fee
blockchain.transactions.subscribe
blockchain.transactions.unsubscribe

firstbits.resolve
firstbits.lookup
```

https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol.html

> check :
>   https://docs.google.com/document/d/17zHy1SUlhgtCMbypO8cHgpWH73V5iUQKk_0rWvMqSNs/edit?hl=en_US#heading=h.qehquy6h3br2